# How to export current activity terminal screen to a text file including all commands run with all output messages

Tags: command-line, log

This sounds simple but I want to export all my commands and their outputs/messages from the terminal screen to a text file so that at later point of time I can refer what commands I run along with their outcomes.

Comment: pls spare me as I am new to Linux

Comment: Presuming that you are using a terminal emulator (and not a real hardware terminal) then what's wrong with copy and paste? Read the documentation of your terminal emulator to find out how to copy text.